# Can you move the position of the Hyperdrive after crafting it

Tags: no-mans-sky

Crafted the Hyperdrive in a not so ideal spot and can't move it , discard it, or really do anything with it other than charge it.

EDIT: I can discard it as usual using R3, just doesn't show up on the menu. Guess that's the way to do move it.