# How do you move an installed upgrade to another slot?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Is it possible to move an installed (active) upgrade from any slot to another one from the same category (without destroying it)?

If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: How can it be in a non-ideal spot? Does the inventory slot it occupies make a difference?

Comment: @toryan not so much the inventory of the hyperdrive but upgrades apparently give more of a boost of placed directly adjacent to the part you're trying to upgrade.  So if i put my hyperdrive top left it screws up two potential boosted upgrades.

Comment: @Atom Reading your last comment I think you might be confused how they work. Upgrades don't have to be directly next to the hyperdrive to get the bonus. You can build upgrades next to another upgrade that is adjacent to the Hyperdrive itself. Sort of like a chain, you can build the Hyperdrive and its upgrades straight in a row if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Beyond](https://www.nomanssky.com/beyond-update/) update, released August 14th 2019, you can now move technology to different slots after being installed.

> Technology can now be moved after installation.

To do this, simply hover over the technology you wish to move and the "Move Technology" option will be in the context menu.

[image: Move technology button]

*<sub>Image taken from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9TNZjMugD8)</sub>*

Comment: Wow... Finally!

Answer (score 9):

Edit:

See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/356130/163757) for a more up to date solution, it should be possible now.

---

**Original Answer:**

As far as I am aware, there is no way to move installed technologies around once they are installed.  This is how the game has been since launch.

One [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281680/can-you-move-the-position-of-the-hyperdrive-after-crafting-it) kind of discusses this, but with a starship hyperdrive technology (which I don't think you need to craft anymore).  Regardless, the only way to "move" an installed technology is to dismantle it, rebuild it, and install it where you want it to be.  You'll unfortunately have to take the hit on the wasted materials.

Comment: Hint: A rebuild is only possible if you have the blueprint. For upgrades which you have paid for with Units (instead of Nanites) you have to find and buy it again.

Comment: This answer was correct until the Beyond update. Therefore I switched the "accepted answer" from this one (Timmy Jim) to the other one (Wondercricket).

Answer (score 4):

You can dismantle it (getting back a small portion of the resources you used to build it) and then build a new one in a different location, but you cannot simply move the Hyperdrive (or any other ship, suit, or multi-tool component) to a new spot

Comment: Which poses real problems for adjacency bonuses!